# C - segmentation fault using struct member values

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct

I'm running head-long into a segmentation fault that I'm not sure of the reason behind.

Short story... I store file names into members of a struct, then use those members to open files to load their data into linked lists.  This is working fine when I only have two file, but when I go to add a third, I get a segmentation fault opening the first file.

Code will hopefully illustrate better...

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /* Initalise tennisStore struct  */
    TennisStoreType *ts;
    systemInit(ts);

    /* Variables */
    ts->stockFile = "stock.csv";
    ts->custFile = "customer.csv";
    ts->salesFile = "sales.csv";

     /* Load data from files */
     loadData(ts, ts->custFile, ts->stockFile);

...
}
```

The struct details for ts...

```
typedef struct tennisStore
{
   CustomerNodePtr headCust;  
   unsigned customerCount;
   StockNodePtr headStock;
   unsigned stockCount;
   char *custFile;
   char *stockFile;
   char *salesFile;
} TennisStoreType;
```

systemInit() seems pretty innocuous, but here's the code just in case...

```
void systemInit(TennisStoreType *ts)
{
    /* Set ts options to be ready */
    ts->headCust = NULL;
    ts->headStock = NULL;
    ts->customerCount = 0;
    ts->stockCount = 0;
}
```

loadData()...

```
void loadData(TennisStoreType* ts, char* customerFile, char* stockFile)
{
    /* Load customer data */
    addCustNode(ts, customerFile);

    /* Load stock data */
    addStockNode(ts, stockFile);
}
```

Here's where the problem occurs...

```
void addStockNode(TennisStoreType* ts, char* stockFile)
{
    /* Variables */
    StockNodePtr head, new, current, previous;
    unsigned stkLevel;
    char *stkTok1, *stkTok2, *stkTok3, *stkTok4;
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    float stkPrice;
    FILE *stream;

    /* Set head */
    head = NULL;

    /* Open stock file  */
    stream = fopen(stockFile, "r");     <-- segmentation fault when sales.csv line   included
    assert(stream);

    while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, stream))
    {
        ...
    }
...
}
```

As above, when the *ts->salesFile = "sales.csv"* line is included in main, the segmentation fault occurs.  When it isn't, all is fine (file opens, I can read from it, write to it etc).  Cannot for the life of me understand why, so I'm appealing to your good nature and superior knowledge of C for potential causes of this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change
`TennisStoreType *ts;`

to

`TennisStoreType *ts=malloc(sizeof(TennisStoreType));`

or

change

```
TennisStoreType *ts;
systemInit(ts);
```

to

```
TennisStoreType ts;
systemInit(&ts);
```

Comment: Thanks, your first suggestion fixed the problem.  Just to clarify, does declaring a struct require a malloc call in every situation (to allocate sufficient memory for the struct)?

Comment: @DeanMackenzie Malloc isn't a necessity as shown in the second example. It depends on the manner in which it is assumed that in the processing of other. (E.g. `free(pointer to address by malloc)`)

Comment: declaring a struct doesn't require a malloc() call to allocate storage, but that wasn't what you did. What you did was declare a pointer to a struct. If you're telling the compiler "this var will be used to hold the address of an object allocated elsewhere", you need to initialize it with the address of an object allocated elsewhere. Such as, for example, through a call to malloc().

Comment: OK, thanks for explanation Elchonon.  That makes quite a bit more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

`ts` is uninitialized, and used as is, in `systemInit()`.
It should be `malloc()`ed..

Comment: Thanks, looks like that was the answer as above.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually created your `TennisStoreType` object.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    TennisStoreType *ts;  // <-- allocates 4 bytes for a pointer
    systemInit(ts);       // <-- pass the pointer to nowhere around.
```

Try inserting `ts = malloc(sizeof(TennisStoreType))` in between those two lines.